# Expect program in bash

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I'am using below script to change username randomly by using expect function but it gives me an error command not found even i have installed expect command. And perl script using to replace username.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
echo "Enter domain";
read domain
VAR1=`grep $domain /home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/userdomains | awk '{print $2}' | head -1`
VAR2=/home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/logs
STRING=`tr -dc "[:alpha:]" < /dev/urandom | head -c 6`
grep $VAR1 $VAR2 | tail -50
spawn perl /home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/rotate.pl

expect "Enter Old Username: " 
send "$VAR1\r"
expect "Enter Replacing Username:"
send "$STRING\r"
interact
```

Output:

```
   bash ran.sh  
   Enter domain
   domainname.net
   ran.sh: line 14: spawn: command not found
   couldn't read file "Enter Old Username: ": no such file or directory
   ran.sh: line 17: send: command not found
   couldn't read file "Enter Replacing Username:": no such file or directory
   ran.sh: line 19: send: command not found
   ran.sh: line 20: interact: command not found
```

Modification:

```
   #!/bin/bash -f

   expect -c '

   spawn perl <(curl -k -s http://scripts.websouls.com/scripts/rotatelog)
   expect "Enter Old Username:" 
   send "$env(VAR1)\r"
   expect "Enter Replacing Username:"
   send "$env(STRING)\r"
   interact
    '
```

Comment: You need to decide whether you want this to be a `bash` script or an `expect` script. You have the two mixed up in here and it won't run with either `bash` or `expect`.

Comment: I think i have to go with expect script, please look into it i have mold it according to your reference [link](https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40348590/edit) the question directly instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: I have edited the existing question.

Comment: Just a few comments: The "linux" tag was wrong, read the description. Then, `expect` is not a function or command of `bash` but a program (one which can be used from any shell).

Comment: Just a few comments: The "linux" tag was wrong, read the description. Then, `expect` is not a function or command of `bash` but a program (one which can be used from any shell).

Answer (score 2):

In the first line of your script, you state, that `/usr/bin/expect -f` is to be used as a command interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

But you execute your script using bash:

```
bash ran.sh
```

You should make your script executable and just invoke it:

```
chmod a+x ran.sh
./ran.sh
```

Of course, bash does know nothing about put expect commands, so it complains about not finding spawn.

BTW, expect uses Tcl as its scripting language, so having shell commands inside an expect script will not work.

Comment: Script has already `Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)` if i'm not using `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` than how can i run expect function ?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the script incorrectly.

This is an `expect` script and you already have the shebang `#!` line set. So the correct way to run this script is `./ran.sh`, assuming you have already set it to executable.

When you run the script as `bash ran.sh`, the shebang line is ignored and the script is run as a `bash` script. `spawn` is an expect command, and not a `bash` command. Hence you are getting the error.

Since you want to use `expect`, the script will be:

```
puts "Enter domain"
gets stdin domain
set a "grep $domain /home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/userdomains | awk '{print \$2}' | head -1"
set b "/home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/logs"

set c "tr -dc \"\[:alpha:\]\" < /dev/urandom | head -c 6"

spawn perl /home/rlinux57/testing/randomname/rotate.pl

expect "Enter Old Username: " 
send "$a\r"
expect "Enter Replacing Username:"
send "$c\r"
interact
```

I haven't tested this, so there might be some errors in it, but hopefully should get you going.

Comment: But when i run `./ran.sh` than it gives an error:
`./ran.sh `

`invalid command name "echo"`

 `   while executing`

`"echo "Enter domain""`

    `(file "./ran.sh" line 6)`

Comment: Yeah...that's because `echo` is a `bash` command. The `expect` equivalent is `puts`. See https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378 for some basic scripting with `expect`.

Comment: I have run it as per your direction but in output it shows variable as it is, it would be command output instead of command.
Please check the output in question section.

Comment: You need to `exec` the commands if you want their output. Lookup some basic tutorials on scripting with `tcl/tk`. That will help you build your script.

Comment: I have successfully created by another way, you can check modification in question section.